# Facebook - Posting to a Group page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am attempting to post on a group page using the FB JS API, basically the user selects the group they want to post onto, and it posts it to the wall.

i am doing:

```
FB.ui(
    {
      method: 'stream.publish',
      from: myId,
      to: groupID,
      attachment: {
        name: 'Post to a group Test,
        href: 'http://www.test.com'
      }
     });
```

But when i try it, it says:

> An invalid target was specified:
>   <(groupid)>. The target must be a
>   page, event, or user that the actor
>   can post on the wall of.

Thou, i know i can post on the group page, so i dont know why it says that.

And i am not talking about fan pages, i can post on them ok setting the from and to as the same thing (posting as an admin).

Is this possible? or am i just doing it wrong?..

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that both `stream.publish` and `feed` methods are not supported for groups object so your best solution is to use (for example) the jQuery UI Dialog component with the fields you need to post to the group as inputs and on the submission use the `FB.api` method:

```
FB.api("/group_id/feed", 'post', { name: nameVar, link: linkVar }, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: This helped, i managed to post to a group now, problem now is i am attaching a flash file, which error out when clicking to play it "There was a problem with the parameters of the request. Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid Request" thou i know the flash link works. Also dosnt support properties, and action links dont seem to work...sigh why is facebook such a pain

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced, with the facebook API, but what is the value of the groupID variable? is it "(groupid)"? 
If not, then it is a really unclear error message - and I wonder how the API knows that you tried to post on a group. 
If so, then there you have it ;-) You should fill in a group id.

Comment: groupID is just the ID of the group, didnt put a specific group id, you can replace groupID with 2403924841, and therefor in the error message replace <(groupid)> with 2403924841 for a more real life example

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentations, Facebook groups are not mentioned in the list of possible targets to publish to. I filed a bug to hopefully get Facebook to address this:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/158247050931954