# How to post an attached link to a facebook group?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can i post my link attachment to a group feed on facebook with this? I think i've done it wrong.

```
function post_to_group() {
    FB.api("/group_id/feed", 'post', {
        message: 'My Sample Post',
        attachment: {
            name: 'Article Name Slugs', 
            href: 'http://mylink.com/article-name-slugs/'
        }
         }, 
            function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log('Error occured: ', response.error);
            } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            }
    });
}
```

here's my reference to what I've done:
[Facebook - Posting to a Group page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803697/facebook-posting-to-a-group-page)

but this shows an error in both my work and the one i reference to -

> {message: "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to
>   perform this action", type: "OAuthException", code: 200}

Comment: Can you show us what permissions you have taken from the user?

Comment: @ashwin, i don't know where to get the list of permissions authorized by the user. can you please tell me where can i find that? is it in the Graph API Explorer? Thanks!

Comment: @ashwin, here's the permissions i selected from Graph API Explorer.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5740869/permissions.png

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'stream.publish',
            from: myId,
            to: groupID,
            attachment: {
                name: 'Post to a group Test',
                href: '...'
            }
        });
```